# how to link two tables in the same database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to link two tables that are in one database please help with syntax

Comment: What do you mean by link? Are you trying to create a foreign key? Also, please tag your post with the database system you are using and provide an example of what you have tried already.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: I mean join when I say link

Comment: There are [nearly 80,000 questions here about using join in MySQL already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=-1&q=mysql%20join&searchOn=1)

Answer (score 0):

BASIC syntax to join two tables

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.column_to_based_the_join_on= table2.column_to_based_the_join_on
```